# How to create a function that would list multiple relation values in one row (SQL Server 2014)

Tags: sql, sql-server

db Northwind

I am supposed to create a new function that returns all the products (table `Products`) for a particular Order(view `[Order Details]`) in a single row, separated by commas BUT I am not supposed to use `FOR XML PATH` like I have done already. My trainer suggested that my `@ProductName` should nest all the Product Names, but I have no idea how to return then  in a single row, without using `FOR XML PATH`. Please look at the code.

```
alter Function FunctionName(@OrderID int)
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin
  declare @ProductName nvarchar(max);

  select @ProductName = (
    SELECT p.ProductName + ',' 
    FROM Products p
    join [Order Details] od on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
    where @OrderID = od.orderID 
    group by p.ProductID, p.ProductName
    FOR XML PATH('')
  )
  return @ProductName;
END;
```

Comment: You can use a recursive cte to achieve this

Comment: `nvarchar(32)` will most likely not be big enough to hold the `ProductName` string with commas. `Returns nvarchar(max)` would be better to declare.

Comment: @Dheerendra i am not sure how, can you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 2):

I *think* the following does what you want:

```
declare @ProductName nvarchar(max);

select @ProductName = coalesce(@ProductName + ',', '') + p.ProductName 
from Products p join
     [Order Details] od
     on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
where @OrderID = od.orderID ;

return @ProductName;
```

I don't recommend this construct, because I'm not 100% sure it is actually guaranteed to work correctly (nor am I aware of warnings against it).  In practice, however, it does work.

Your trainer, however, should not be encouraging you to look for tricks in the language.  Instead, s/he should be teaching you about `string_agg()`, which is available starting in SQL Server 2017.